# How can we receive and Transmit data packets Through UDP over the network(Socket Programing) iPhone xcode

Tags: xcode, sockets, udp

I am a noob to Socket Programming I want to transmit and receive the data packets using UDP over a network.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at AsyncUdpSocket it's all you need !!
Feel free to ask more and please choose my answer if u like it ;)